# Is "Being a ..." grammatically incorrect?

Tags: american-english, british-english

This is a pet peeve - I automatically correct all instances of "Being a (woman/ avid reader/ general irritable person etc.)" to "As a...".

Intuition tells me "Being a " is incorrect. However, I have seen three instances of its use in articles today alone, and many more prior to this - is this a widely propagated mistake that I can continue to (forcefully) correct?

Comment: No.  Rational students of language aren't allowed pet peeves.  English is not your own private language.

Comment: @Greg Lee Your opinion is appreciated, but a pet peeve is surely personal. It would be different if my choice of alternative was incorrect (which it has not proved).

Comment: You cannot correct it, because you are wrong, and the original is perfectly fine and grammatical. Stop it. Stop it right now. And never, ever, do it again! ;-)

Comment: Talking about pet peeves, why do you write "prior to"  (two words, three syllables, Latinate) instead of the single two-syllable English word, "before"?

Answer (score 2):

Both ways, how the sentence is written and how you read it, are correct. *Being* is here a participle introducing a participial phrase that modifies the subject of the sentence, and your replacement with *as* will preserve the phrase's meaning in all instances I can imagine currently.

Comment: thanks - but I think I may have phrased the question in an unclear manner earlier. I take from your answer too however that "Being a ..." is not incorrect.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear answer (the fault was mine). Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth noting that the few dictionaries that list ***being*** as a *conjunction*, do so with reservations:

- [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/being): *Nonstandard.*
- [Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/being): *Chiefly Dial*.
- [American Heritage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/being): *Chiefly Southern US, Upper Southern US, & New England*

Comment: The nonstandard usage cited, such as "*Being it's midnight, let's go home*", is different from the OP's examples, such as "*being an avid reader*".